# Styling a UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

In my app I want to present an `ActionSheet`, a `UIAlertController` with some options. Anything works, but I'd like to style this controller a little because the standard colors are fairly different from the UI the graphic artist produced. Is there any way to style a `UIAlertController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the `alert.view.backgroundColor` and `alert.view.tintColor`

Comment: Is this something a little "hacky"? I could not find any docs

Comment: @IanBell no this isn't "hacky" `UIAlertController` is just a subclass of a `UIView` and all `UIViews` have the `view` property.

Comment: Hmmm. Small point. `UIAlertController` is a subclass of UIViewController. alert.view is the UIView.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally you should be able to change its appearance via its `appearance` proxy!

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this